# Ubuntu 14.04 does not run on IBM Thinkpad T61 (?)

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, thinkpad, error-handling

I have a T61 Notebook. On this, *Ubuntu 12.04 LTS* runs OK.

Now I would like to upgrade to **14.04 LTS**.

Using the same USB stick, I setup the netbook. It runs!

The 'Setup' for 12.04 runs, but 14.04 stalls after: '**Battery check....[ok]**'

Nothing works. Any key or combination-Key does nothing. Only if I press the Power-Buttom, then the PC goes down and *shuts off*.

*Can anybody help me?*

Comment: When you say "I setup the netbook. It runs!", do you mean that you successfully installed 14.04, but it then hung booting from the hard drive? Or did the installer itself hang while booting? Either way, remove 'splash quiet' from the boot args and add 'debug' and try booting, you will probably get a more informative error message.

Comment: I also want to install ubuntu on a Lenovo Thinkpad T61. Did it work with 14.04 or you have to use 12.04? Regards,
Carlos

Answer (score -1):

I also had the weirdest behavior from a burned DVD w/ U 14.04

I started to boot (little symbol of a open arms man) and then the video went black and boot finished with a small red/green block in the middle/bottom.

I could only work around by connecting a Lenovo external monitor and closing the lid just after pressing power on.

So, it could be a notebook monitor issue. If you have an external (kinda old - late 2007) monitor, try this. I had to open the lid to use the keyboard eventually and it continued to work. Then the notebook screen became the principal one...

Hope it helps, have a good one!